# Amazon Associates - Reporting on revenue generated by particular pages?

Tags: amazon

Is there any feature in the Amazon affiliates system which will allow be to know, for a given month, what revenue was generated by individual pages?

Perhaps e.g. by adding a querystring param to the referral link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tracking ids for this.

> With tracking IDs, Associates can
>   analyze the performance of various Web
>   sites or merchandising strategies
>   while accumulating earnings under a
>   single Associates ID. For example,
>   Associate storeid-20 might use the
>   tracking ID storeid-1-20 to track
>   referrals from one section of his Web
>   site, and storeid-2-20 to track
>   referrals from another section.

https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/help/t1/a8?ie=UTF8&pf_rd_t=501&ref_=amb_link_126306_1&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=&pf_rd_s=assoc-center-2&pf_rd_r=&pf_rd_i=assoc_help_t10

So you want a different tracking id for each page.